# How to specify the abstract class descendant at construction time of the instance of another class?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Consider the high-level dataset class `Data` that uses the abstract underlying implementation of low-level I/O:

```
class basic_io {};
class mmf_file_io: public basic_io {};
class std_file_io: public basic_io {};

class Data
{
public:
   Data(basic_io* io);
protected: 
   basic_io* m_io_backend;
};
```

How do I provide a certain choise of I/O backend - `mmf_file_io` or `std_file_io` during the instantiation of `Data` instance without explicily creating an instance of `mmf_file_io` or `std_file_io` respectively and then passing in to `Data` constructor?

Comment: Why not pass it to the constructor? It's the common pattern of "dependency injection", and it makes it very easy to write tests for your `Data` class (think about a `mock_file_io`...). You can have static functions that prepopulate certain kinds of Data if you really want to.

Comment: @KerrekSB I want the backend to be `protected`, but if I instantiate it manually then pass to `Data` constructor, it would violate the protection, since I would have the control of `basic_io` instance from aside. I should just somehow hint the constructor which type of I/O to use so it can instantiate it himself and have exclusive control over it. Of course, I don't want to do a `switch - case` ladder inside the constructor.

Comment: You can make the constructor protected, and, as I said, use static class members to create objects: `static Data MmfData() { return Data(std::make_unique<mmf_file_io>("foo", "bar")); }` etc.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think I'd implement an abstract "generator" class, like `basic_io_gen` that would contain a private `create()` function returning new instance of `basic_io` class. Actual `basic_io_gen` descendants would re-implement this generator to return the actual descendant of `basic_io`.